# Cannot find class even when jar file is in working directory

Tags: java, classpath, aix

I am struggling to get my Java program to run on AIX. I used Eclipse on Windows to create a runnable Jar file, `jRams.jar` below. I kept on getting a class not found error, until finally I put all the external libraries in the same directory.

```
$ ls
JAXB2_20081030.jar
JAXB2_20110601.jar
activation.jar
asjava.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-jxpath-1.3.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar
jRams.jar
jaxb-api.jar
jaxb-impl.jar
jaxb-xjc.jar
jaxb1-impl.jar
jremote.jar
jsr173_1.0_api.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
netty-3.2.4.Final.jar
$
```

Still, I get the class not found error.

```
$ java -jar jRams.jar
The java class is not found:  com.jbase.jremote.JRemoteException
```

`jremote.jar` definitely contains JRemoteException. Why isn't this working?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your straight-to-the-point answers. I now understand the nature of a java application and a manifest file far better.

Turns out my ftp client was transferring in ASCII mode and not Binary, so the jar files were corrupt. I have learned a great deal, nonetheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `-jar` option, you need to specify which jar-files should be on your class path in the [manifest file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). Just having the required jar files in the same directory won't do it.

Add a line in your manifest that says:

```
Class-Path: JAXB2_20081030.jar:JAXB2_20110601.jar:....:netty-3.2.4.Final.jar
```

or skip the `-jar` option and launch using

```
java -cp JAXB2_20081030.jar:....:netty-3.2.4.Final.jar:jRams.jar pkg.JRamsMain
```

and it should work fine.

(Note that on *nix systems, as opposed to Windows machines, the jar files in the class paths should be separated using `:` instead of `;`.)

**Further reading:**

- [The Java Tutorials: Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all those JARs to the runtime `CLASSPATH` by adding the `-classpath` parameter.  AIX requires you to separate the JARs using `:`

Comment: When using the `-jar` option the `-classpath` option is ignored. From `man java` on `-jar`: *When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.*

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the full path(if libraries not in the same directory as `jRams`) or just the names of the jar file in a manifest file (If all dependency jars are in the same folder). Alternative specify the path to all the dependent *jars* using `-cp` argument.

**Example** (*This assume every dependency is in the same directory you are executing java command from*):

`java -cp commons-collections-3.2.1.jar; jaxb-impl.jar; etc.. ;jRams.jar package_to_class.MyMainClass.java`

Where `package_to_class` is example: `com.myproj.example`.

**EDITED**.

Comment: When using the `-jar` option the `-classpath` option is ignored. From `man java` on `-jar`: *When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.*

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add "Class-Path" to existing jar file -

1. Create "newmanifest" file with following entry
   Class-Path: additional/jars
2. Update existing jar file e.g. "classes.jar"
   jar --update --manifest=newmanifest --file classes.jar
3. Inflate jar file
   jar -xvf classes.jar
   created: META-INF/
   inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
4. Verify "Class-Path" is added to MANIFEST.MF

cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
main-class: CLASSNAME
Created-By: 15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: additional/jars