# Additional jar files for java.exe -jar

Tags: java, jar

I run the following command:

```
C:\Projects\java -cp ./dependency.jar -jar ./dist/main.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: Main. Program will exit.
```

MyException is inside dependency.jar. I also tried to replace -cp with -classpath. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-cp` options is ignored if you use `-jar`. If you need extra jar-files on the class-path, you should specify this in the Manifest of `main.jar` like this:

```
Class-Path: dependency.jar
```

(Then you can run your program using `java -jar main.jar`.)

**Related questions:**

- [When creating a jar file how do I retain the existing classpaths to other jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742355/when-creating-a-jar-file-how-do-i-retain-the-existing-classpaths-to-other-jar-fi)
- [Cannot find class even when jar file is in working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469711/cannot-find-class-even-when-jar-file-is-in-working-directory)
- [Jetty Classpath issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537390/jetty-classpath-issues)
- [problem related to MANIFEST.MF in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678524/problem-related-to-manifest-mf-in-jar)

Comment: A good alternative is to make a single jar that bundles all dependencies. search for "jar-with-dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the class path in the windows environment variable CLASSPATH ?

specify your environment variable CLASSPATH and put the value of your JAVA_HOME\lib and (path to all your classes) and also include current directory by including (dot or period sign).

Comment: THe CLASSPATH environment variable is ignored when you use the `-jar` option.